# Post данные с перенаправлением

Tags: post, php, http

Подскажите пожалуйста как можно с 1 пхп страницы перенаправить на другую и одновременно послать пост данные ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задавался подобным вопросом и в конечно итоге пришёл к мнению что перенаправлять пост это либо ошибка в построении php приложения, либо вы хотите украсть чужие POST данные, записать себе а потом как ни в чём не бывало перенаправить на верный сайт. Но всё же, если задача специфичная, то вот небольшая наработка на примере формы авторизации Контактика:

route.php

```
<?php
/* тут делаете чё хотите с пост данными */
?>
<form action="http://vk.com/" name="myform" method="post">
  <?php foreach ($_POST as $key => $val) { ?>
     <input name="<?php echo $key; ?>" value="<?php echo $val; ?>" type="hidden" />
  <?php } ?>
</form>
<script>
  document.forms["myform"].submit();
</script>
```

Comment: А можно это сделать на стороне конкретно сервера ? У меня ситуация когда я получаю данные из node.js на страницу к примеру 1.php обрабатываю их, формирую данные для вида и хочу передать на страницу 2.php что бы не нервничать.

Comment: Если обрабатывать на сервере, могу подсказать эту статью: http://habrahabr.ru/post/48726/ и примеры: http://docs.php.net/manual/ru/context.http.php